# how to "deploy" Django from htaccess

Tags: django, apache

Is there a way to manage/deploy the Django Handler with htaccess
because I'm not allowed to modify apache configuration file.

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried what is suggested in the section *Running Django on a Shared-Hosting Provider with Apache* of the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/) ?

Comment: Your link to Django book is broken.